# Rank based in condition in redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have the following data set:

```
id | bool_col | datetime_col
1  | N        | 2017-01-01 00:01:00
2  | N        | 2017-01-01 00:02:00
3  | N        | 2017-01-01 00:03:00
4  | Y        | 2017-01-01 00:04:00
5  | N        | 2017-01-01 00:05:00
6  | N        | 2017-01-01 00:06:00
7  | N        | 2017-01-01 00:07:00
8  | Y        | 2017-01-01 00:08:00
9  | N        | 2017-01-01 00:09:00
10 | N        | 2017-01-01 00:10:00
11 | N        | 2017-01-01 00:11:00
12 | N        | 2017-01-01 00:12:00
13 | Y        | 2017-01-01 00:13:00
```

I need to add an extra column with a rank that separates each chunk that ends with a Y in the bool_col:

```
id | bool_col | datetime_col        | rank
1  | N        | 2017-01-01 00:01:00 | 1
2  | N        | 2017-01-01 00:02:00 | 1
3  | N        | 2017-01-01 00:03:00 | 1
4  | Y        | 2017-01-01 00:04:00 | 1
5  | N        | 2017-01-01 00:05:00 | 2
6  | N        | 2017-01-01 00:06:00 | 2
7  | N        | 2017-01-01 00:07:00 | 2
8  | Y        | 2017-01-01 00:08:00 | 2
9  | N        | 2017-01-01 00:09:00 | 3
10 | N        | 2017-01-01 00:10:00 | 3
11 | N        | 2017-01-01 00:11:00 | 3
12 | N        | 2017-01-01 00:12:00 | 3
13 | Y        | 2017-01-01 00:13:00 | 3
```

I have tried many iterations of lead, lag and rank, but still no clue of how to tell it to increase the rank only if there is a Y in the bool_col

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply do a cumulative sum of the number of "Y"s before each value.  In your case:

```
select t.*,
       (1 + sum(case when bool_col is true then 1 else 0 end) over (order by id rows between unbounded preceding and current row)) as rnk
from t;
```

Note:  This uses `is true`, assuming the column really is boolean.  Otherwise, use something like `= 'Y'`.

Comment: Freaking amazing, such a simple approach, I've been fighting with this all day. Please just add the frame clause so I can mark as correct. I used this: rows between unbounded preceding and current row